# my video wallpaper is not autostarting

Tags: lubuntu, video, desktop-background, autostart, mpv-media-player

This is a summary of my attempts from [how do I make this gif into a wallpaper from Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424486):

I'm running Lubuntu 18.04.

After deciding that I want to use a video as my wallpaper, I got my window ID from `xwininfo`, then I created a `video-wallpaper.desktop` file and placed it inside `/home/ardouronerous/.config/autostart/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Video Wallpaper
Exec=mpv -loop-file=inf --osc=no --cursor-autohide=no --wid=<ID> /home/ardouronerous/Videos/video.mp4
```

It works on startup, but the downside to using this is that the value of the window ID changes, so I have to get the value of window ID from `xwininfo` and change `wid=<ID>` in my `video-wallpaper.desktop` every time it changes, it's inconvenient.

After getting my window ID from `wmctrl -l` this is my next attempt:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Video Wallpaper
Exec=bash -c "mpv -loop-file=inf --osc=no --cursor-autohide=no --wid=$(wmctrl -l|awk '/<ID>/ {print $1}') /home/ardouronerous/Videos/video.mp4"
```

This doesn't work on autostar. When I restart my PC, the video doesn't start, however, when I click on the `video-wallpaper.desktop` file or when the command in exec is executed in the Terminal, the video starts.

These are my other attempts, which all failed to get my desired results:

```
mpv -loop-file=inf --osc=no --cursor-autohide=no --geometry=100%:100% /home/ardouronerous/Videos/video.mp4
```

The problem with this one is that the titlebar is visible on top and the video is present on the taskbar.

```
mpv -loop-file=inf --osc=no --cursor-autohide=no --no-borders --geometry=100%:100% /home/ardouronerous/Videos/video.mp4
```

The problem here is that the video becomes fullscreen, covering the taskbar.

Comment: Instead of specifying geometry the way you have in the last code, why not look at the Applications section of your ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml and see if you can have an Application rule that does what you want. The Applications section is pretty powerful and worth understanding. I don't use wallpapers and so won't be more helpful.

Comment: I managed to make it run on startup with the following command:

`bash -c "sleep 5; mpv -loop-file=inf --osc=no --cursor-autohide=no --wid=$(wmctrl -l|awk '/<ID>/ {print $1}') /home/ardouronerous/Videos/video.mp4"`

Comment: My guess is that when this command is ran at startup it does so before the X session is ready or it does so in a context where `DISPLAY` is not set.